# Replace "*" in filenames with "All"

Tags: rename

Using Unix

```
Linux tinaroo1.local 3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Oct 20 20:32:50 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I saw a few files that have a * in their name

```
1000_*_Map_20220926182235.csv
16000_*_48_Result_Lead_20220926200445.csv
```

how can I rename all files in one command to rename * with "All"

so these files will become

```
1000_All_Map_20220926182235.csv
16000_All_48_Result_Lead_20220926200445.csv
```

Comment: What is the OS?

Comment: Linux tinaroo1.local 3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Oct 20 20:32:50 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: @NasirRiley After a simple search, it looks like [an CentOS 7](https://buildlogs.centos.org/c7.1708.u/kernel/20171023132245/3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64/).

Answer (score 2):

Using the bash shell (common in GNU/Linux installations):

```bash
for file in ./*\**
do 
  [ -f "$file" ] || continue
  echo mv -- "${file}" "${file/\*/All}"
done
```

This loops over files that have an asterisk (`*`) in their filename somewhere; because the asterisk is a wildcard character for the shell, we have to escape it where we want a literal asterisk to be; the other two are to match any/all of the other characters around the literal asterisk. Each matching filename is then sent into the loop as a variable `$file`. The first command in the loop checks to see if we're dealing with a plain file or not; we skip anything that isn't a plain file. The next command -- `mv` -- would rename the file. The new filename is generated using bash's parameter expansion; the syntax says: replace the first asterisk character (escaped again, to match the actual asterisk) and replace it with the text `All`.

The loop uses `echo` to show what would happen; remove the `echo` to allow the renames to happen.

I've done two specific things to safeguard against odd filenames:

1. Prefixed the initial wildcard (originally `*\**`) with `./`; this ensures that every `$file` filename starts with `./`; for example, `./1000_All_Map_20220926182235.csv`; as a result, the filename will not (cannot) start with a hyphen, potentially causing misinterpretation by the `mv` command as an option.
2. As another layer of protection against "option misinterpretation", I've signaled the end of options for `mv` by adding `--` before providing the filenames.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `rename` from the `util-linux` package, which may already be installed on your system.

Perform a dry run:

```
rename -nv '*' All *
```

Rename the files:

```
rename '*' All *
```

Note that the asterisk in the expression to match must be quoted to prevent shell expansion. Expressions are matched using fixed strings and not regular expressions so no escaping is required.

Answer (score 1):

Obligatory `zsh` answer:

```
autoload -Uz
zmv -n '(**/)(*[*]*.csv)' '$1${2//[*]/All}'
```

(remove `-n` for dry-run if happy).

Answer (score 1):

Using `find` would be useful if you have several subdirectories etc., with files you want to rename. Then calling the Perl-based `rename` utility (sometimes called `prename`) to do the actual renaming:

```bash
find . -name '*[*]*' -type f -exec rename -n -d 's/[*]/All/' {} +
```

This would find all regular files with names that include at least one `*` character, in or below the current directory.  These would be given in batches to `rename` that would replace the first `*` in the name with the string `All`.

The `rename` utility would not rename anything unless you remove the `-n` from the command. You would test-run the command with the `-n` in place first. The `-d` option ensures that the `rename` utility only renames the pathname component at the end, i.e. the file's name, and leaves the directory part unchanged, even though it may also potentially contain a `*` character.

Comment: I got this error 
rename: invalid option -- 'n'

Usage:
 rename [options] expression replacement file...

Options:
 -v, --verbose    explain what is being done
 -s, --symlink    act on symlink target

 -h, --help     display this help and exit
 -V, --version  output version information and exit

For more details see rename(1).
ak/__Files>

Comment: @asmgx The command in probably called `prename` in your Linux distribution.

Answer (score 0):

As this is either RHEL 7 or CentOS 7, in addition to the other answer, the perl rename utility is available.

If it's not installed

```
yum install prename -y
```

If you just want to replace all files that contain a `*` in their name:

```
prename -n 's/\*/All/' ./*
```

It will only operate on the files whose names contain `*` and the `-n` switch will send what happened to stdout instead of operating on the files. The `*` is a special character to both the shell and perl regexps. We use single quotes to escape it from the shell and `\` in the regexp for it to lose its special regexp operator meaning. Alternatives would be `'s/[*]/All/'` or `'s/\Q*\E/All/'.

Once satisfied with the result, remove the `-n` switch.

Comment: @roaima Saw that on the man page last night but was dead tired and was vacuumed into the bed. In any event, I've added it to my answer.